# How to make graph in Laravel 5.2

Tags: graph, laravel-5, user-registration

I am new in laravel and want to make graph for the user registration.I want a visual representation of the registration process that whether the registration increases or decreases in a month.

Answer (score 1):

If its a part of Admin panel: You can use AdminLte below is Link for the same

https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

whichever Part of graph You need you can Copy paste the same Html in your Blade file and Provide the necessary data from the controller

Based on your requirement you'll have to hit a Query on users table and you'll have to group by result based on months and plot the values in the graph.

Hope this Helps you.

Comment: Did this help you??

Comment: can you accept it as the answer so that others who refer to the post finds the answer. Glad to help you